# The following classes could not be instantiated: - com.wonderkiln.camerakit.CameraView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am using 0.13.1 CameraKit dependency and it is giving the following Exception. I have tried almost every possible way. changing this dependency to the latest 1.0.0 version is not possible because then I would have to edit the whole code and change it as they had changed a lot of things in the new version, I tried to change it but couldn't change the whole code and all required parts.

CameraKit could not be instantiated and gives a NUllPointerException:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(Camera.java:295)
    at com.wonderkiln.camerakit.Camera1.frontCameraOnly(Camera1.java:648)
    at com.wonderkiln.camerakit.CameraView.<init>(CameraView.java:140)
    at com.wonderkiln.camerakit.CameraView.<init>(CameraView.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:404)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:187)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:145)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:309)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:417)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:428)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:332)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1097)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:501)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:328)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:396)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:209)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:608)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$6(RenderTask.java:734)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Here is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.wonderkiln.camerakit.CameraView
        android:id="@+id/camera_View"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="689dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
         />

    <com.waqad.facedetectionmodule.Helper.GraphicOverlay
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/graphic_overlay"
        android:layout_above="@id/detectFace"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/detectFace"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/camera_View"
        android:text="@string/detect_face_btnText"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the MainActivity.java class

```
package com.waqad.facedetectionmodule;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import dmax.dialog.SpotsDialog;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.FirebaseVision;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.common.FirebaseVisionImage;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.face.FirebaseVisionFace;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.face.FirebaseVisionFaceDetector;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.face.FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions;
import com.waqad.facedetectionmodule.Helper.GraphicOverlay;
import com.waqad.facedetectionmodule.Helper.RectOverlay;
import com.wonderkiln.camerakit.CameraKitError;
import com.wonderkiln.camerakit.CameraKitEvent;
import com.wonderkiln.camerakit.CameraKitEventListener;
import com.wonderkiln.camerakit.CameraKitImage;
import com.wonderkiln.camerakit.CameraKitVideo;
import com.wonderkiln.camerakit.CameraView;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private Button faceDetectButton;
    private GraphicOverlay graphicOverlay;
    private CameraView cameraView;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        faceDetectButton = findViewById(R.id.detectFace);
        graphicOverlay = findViewById(R.id.graphic_overlay);
        cameraView = findViewById(R.id.camera_View);

        alertDialog = new SpotsDialog.Builder()
                .setContext(this)
                .setMessage("Please wait, Processing ...")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .build();

        faceDetectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                cameraView.start();
                cameraView.captureImage();
                graphicOverlay.clear();
            }
        });

        cameraView.addCameraKitListener(new CameraKitEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(CameraKitEvent cameraKitEvent) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(CameraKitError cameraKitError) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onImage(CameraKitImage cameraKitImage) {
                alertDialog.show();
                Bitmap bitmap =cameraKitImage.getBitmap();
                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, cameraView.getWidth(), cameraView.getHeight(), false);
                cameraView.stop();

                processFaceDatection(bitmap);
            }

            @Override
            public void onVideo(CameraKitVideo cameraKitVideo) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void processFaceDatection(Bitmap bitmap) {
        FirebaseVisionImage firebaseVisionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(bitmap);
        FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions firebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions =
                new FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.Builder().build();
        FirebaseVisionFaceDetector firebaseVisionFaceDetector = FirebaseVision.getInstance()
                .getVisionFaceDetector(firebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions);

        firebaseVisionFaceDetector.detectInImage(firebaseVisionImage).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<FirebaseVisionFace>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<FirebaseVisionFace> firebaseVisionFaces) {
                getFaceResults(firebaseVisionFaces);
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error! " + e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        });

    }

    private void getFaceResults(List<FirebaseVisionFace> firebaseVisionFaces) {
        int counter=0;
        for (FirebaseVisionFace face : firebaseVisionFaces){
            Rect rect = face.getBoundingBox();
            RectOverlay rectOverlay = new RectOverlay(graphicOverlay, rect);

            graphicOverlay.add(rectOverlay);
            counter += 1;
        }

        alertDialog.dismiss();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        cameraView.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        cameraView.stop();
    }
}
```

My app level (build.gradle)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.waqad.facedetectionmodule"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.wonderkiln:camerakit:0.13.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:1.1@aar'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: That is not a runtime error in the app. That is an error in the IDE, from the graphical layout editor. There is nothing much you can do about that, other than to avoid the graphical layout editor.

Comment: So it would not affect the working of my application?

Comment: Correct. Custom widgets like `CameraView` need some logic to avoid doing anything unusual when in the graphical layout editor, as the IDE is actually running the real widget code to render the preview. `CameraView` does not have that logic, so it tries to access a camera that does not exist. But, you should be able to run the project despite this complaint, and this particular problem will not affect the runtime behavior of your app.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And should I remove this question from here?
And I am actually getting another error: Compatible side by side NDK version was not found. Default is 20.0.5594570.
Can you help me with that?

Comment: @CommonsWare And I am actually getting another error: Compatible side by side NDK version was not found. Default is 20.0.5594570. Can you help me with that?

Comment: That one I do not recognize. You will need to research that. If you cannot find details about it, ask a separate Stack Overflow question with the full build error.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

That is not a runtime error in the app. That is an error in the IDE, from the graphical layout editor. There is nothing much you can do about that, other than to avoid the graphical layout editor. It is possible that this is fixed in a newer version of the library, but you seem opposed to upgrading, so...

What is going on is that custom widgets like `CameraView` need some logic to avoid doing anything unusual when in the graphical layout editor (`isInEditMode()`), as the IDE is actually running the real widget code to render the preview. `CameraView` does not have that logic, so it tries to access a camera that does not exist. But, you should be able to run the project despite this complaint, and this particular problem will not affect the runtime behavior of your app.